# datatable to return date only column and also when exported to csv

Tags: c#

I have datatable with datetime column needs exporting to csv file. User requirement is to display the csv file output without time in the column. Code below generates a csv file with date and time. Is it possible to display the columns in date only format? User should also be able to sort the column once exported to csv.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            var details = LoadDetails();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = details.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                              Select(column => column.ColumnName);
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

            foreach (DataRow row in details.Rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\MyTest.csv", sb.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
           

        }

        private static DataTable LoadDetails()
        {
            DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable("Details");
            dtDetails.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime)); //is there anyway to set to date only 


            var dates = new DateTime[] { DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),  DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)};

            foreach (var date in dates)
            {
                DataRow dtRow = dtDetails.NewRow();
                dtRow["Date"] = date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //output still show date and time

                dtDetails.Rows.Add(dtRow);
            }

            return dtDetails;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Either change the column type to `string`, or move the formatting up to the other `for each` in `Main()`

Comment: Your DataRow data type is `DateTime`, why are you trying to set a string? Change in `dtRow["Date"] = date.Date;` If you want to **format** the DateTime object, use the `.ToString()` method to specify a **String format**: `.Select(field => field.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. BTW, that method to add a Row is convoluted, it's just, e.g., `dtDetails.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now); dtDetails.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));` etc. Use an `object[]` if you need to add more than one Field.

Comment: the `LoadDetails` method doesn't make much sense. The parameters are ignored and aren't used for anything,  and the array `dates1 ` is not the  collection you're iterating `dates`.

Answer (score 0):

Store the DateTime with a time and format it to a timeless string upon output:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in details.Rows)
        {
            var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field is DateTime d ? d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : field.ToString());
            
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }
```

This way asks if the object is holding a datetime and if it is, formats it to dd/MM/yyyy, otherwise it just uses the normal ToString() - presuming at some point you'll have other stuff in your table too

Answer (score 0):

If the `LoadDetails` method is there to generate a DataTable solely for the purposes of generating CSV output, then just set all the column types to `string` and push in the explicit format expressions you want to see in the output.

e.g.

```
private static DataTable LoadDetails(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataTable dtDetails = new DataTable("Details");
    dtDetails.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string)); // Not a DateTime type any more

    var dates1 = new DateTime[] { DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),  DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)};

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        DataRow dtRow = dtDetails.NewRow();
        dtRow["Date"] = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // output now only contains date text.

        dtDetails.Rows.Add(dtRow);
    }

    return dtDetails;
}
```

Also, caution that dates formatted dd/MM/yyyy can be misinterpreted if being processed on machines with different regionalisation settings e.g. USA expecting MM/dd/yyyy. I much prefer to render months in 3-char name format MMM.